# Setting up u vector when using lsim

Tags: matlab, ode

I have a frustrating error when using Matlab where I'm trying to simulate a continuous time system in discrete time.

```
Ts = 0.01;
A=[-0.313 0 56.7;
    0 56.7 0;
    -0.0139 0 0.426];
B = [0.232; 0; 0.0203];
C = [0 1 0];
D = 0;

SYSC = ss(A,B,C,D);
SYSD = c2d(SYSC,Ts);

t = linspace(0,10,10/0.01)';
u = zeros(1000,3);
u(:) = 0.2;
lsim(SYSD,u,t);
```

I am getting the error:

```
When simulating the response to a specific input signal, the
input data U must be a matrix with as many rows as samples in
the time vector T, and as many columns as input channels
```

What is meant by input channels here? Overall I'm not sure how I can fix this error. I have a set time for which I want the simulation to run but I do not know how to set up my vector of inputs correctly. I am modeling three states.

Answer (score 1):

If your input matrix is `B = [0.232; 0; 0.0203]` and is a 3-by-1 column vector, then the linear system given by `A*x + B*u` only has one control input.

So `u` should be:

```
u = zeros(1000,1);
u(:) = 0.2;
```

And you can simulate the discrete time system using

```
lsim(SYSD,u,[]);
```

Note that you don't need to define the time vector in `lsim` for the discrete simulation because `u` is sampled at the same rate as `SYSD`.

If the `B` matrix was 3-by-3, then you would need to have 3 control inputs.

Comment: Your answer regarding the size of t makes sense. But taking your approach gives me an output of all zeros, which should not be happening. Also why is the t argument empty here? I want to simulate for a specified length of time. In fact, making u and t the same vector size throws the error above. I am confused on this.